# Normal distribution, probability and modulus question

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, absolute-value

Say $X$ is a random variable which is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

How do I find $k$ such that

$$\mathbb{P}(|X-k| < |X+k|) = 0.7$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such $k$ does not exist. We have that
\begin{align*}
|X+k|-|X-k|
&=\frac{(|X+k|-|X-k|)(|X+k|+|X-k|)}{|X+k|+|X-k|}\\
&=\frac{|X+k|^2-|X-k|^2}{|X+k|+|X-k|}\\
&=\frac{4kX}{|X+k|+|X-k|}.
\end{align*}
Hence, $|X+k|-|X-k|>0$ if and only if $X>0$ when $k>0$ and $|X+k|-|X-k|>0$ if and only if $X<0$ when $k<0$. The probability does not depend on $k$ if $k\ne0$. We obtain
$$
P(|X-k|<|X+k|)=\frac12
$$
if $k\ne0$ and it is equal to $0$ if $k=0$.

Comment: This can be done much more simple. See my hint: $P(X>0)=\frac12\neq0.7$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If $k>0$ then:$$|x-k|<|x+k|\iff x>0$$

In words: to be more close to $k>0$ instead of $-k$ (on the same distance of $0$ as $k$, but on the other side) it is necessary and sufficient that $x>0$.

---

**edit**:

Consequently $P(|X-k|<|X+k|)=P(X>0)=0.5\neq0.7$.

Conclusion: $k$ cannot be positive.

Likewise it can be shown that $k$ cannot be negative.

Evidently $P(|X|<|X|)=0\neq0.7$ so $k$ cannot take value $0$.

Final conclusion: no such $k$ exists.